# Javascript multiple select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I am trying to create multiple select boxes. So I list in one box which I want to move to two other boxes. When I move item from one list to other , item gets moved from that list and I want to keep it in that list and clone into other list..When I use clone function , its not getting passed from view to controller

```
 return !$('#orim option:selected').clone().appendTo('#reqnew');
```

So when I use above code its just dodnt pass any value to the backend in grails

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zsy3um1o/11/#&togetherjs=3IHNKlan6G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So By getting value and append it to new div and original list helped the problem ..But I am still not sure why appending cloned object didn't work .

```
var options =  $('#ori').find(':selected').clone();
$('#ori').find(':selected').appendTo('#reqm');
options.prependTo('#ori');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass data from the view to a controller you need to implement ajax. So for example in the list1 you need to add some relevant information maybe store it in a html5 data attribute, and then using jquery ajax function or axios among many others solutions pass does data to a controller action and from there perform your back-end logic

Comment: Before passing it to controller I need to move data from box a to box b ..but when I move i want to copy not delete from the original box..When i use clone it doent reach to controller but whe i use .selected .append it reaches to controller..Not able to understand why?